# Search API Number Found Accuracy

Tags: google-app-engine, search

When using the Search API we have the option of paging results by setting a limit and offset for the results. We also have the option to return the total number of search results by using the 'number_found' property. In the docs it clearly states that this number is an approximation and not an exact count.

My issue is, in our production application this approximation is wildly inaccurate (e.g. it reports 1200 matches when only 200 records exist). For now we could simply set the 'number_found_accuracy' to the 'MAXIMUM_NUMBER_FOUND_ACCURACY' constant in our query options, however this will only suffice for a month or two until the number of indexed documents exceeds that constant.

For our purposes the 'number_found' count doesn't have to be exact but we would prefer it be close. All that being said, what are my options for ensuring that as the number of documents stored and indexed grow that the document counts remain relatively accurate?

Comment: Not really a solution but we as a group (the group I work with) basically decided that after 10,000 search results (that is the MAXIMUM_NUMBER_FOUND_ACCURACY value) we really don't care if it's off by a few hundred.